# Issues with reading req undefined inside some functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get user query information when use req.user at first time but in second inside function I got cannot read property user of null.

```
 router.post("/orders", function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.user);//here I can see user info!
        orders.count({
            customerInfo: req.user//here I can get user info!
        }, function (req, count) {
            if (count > 0) {
                console.log(count);
                orders.findOne({
                    customerInfo: req.user//here:cannot read property user of null
                }, function (err, orders) {
                    products.findOne({
                        _id: req.body.id
                    }, function (err, products) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            orders.productInfo.push(products);
                            orders.save(function (err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                } else {
                                    console.log(data);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have req in the inner function and it's overriding the outter req with the user. You can create a var outside with the user:

Example:

```
post("/orders", function (req, res)      { 
  const user = req.user;
  orders.count({ customerInfo: user//here I can get user info! 
   }, function (req, count) { 
 //Here you can use user
   });
});
```

In my opinion your code is what we call callback hell, so it's advisable to refactor It using control flow,  you can use promises, generator functions and other artifacts for this cases.